# How to add all the user inputs in a while loop?

Tags: python, input, sum, average

```
x=input("Do you want to enter number Y/N:")
numbersEntered= 0
while x == "Y":
    number = int(input("Enter number :"))
    numbersEntered=numbersEntered+1
    y=input("Do you want to continue entering new numbers: Y/N:")
    if y == "N":
        break
average=/numbersEntered

print(average)
```

Using Python.This is what I have so far. I need to add all the user inputs together once the user enters "N". I just do not know how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't 'need to add all the user inputs together once the user enters "N"', *per se*.

Create a new variable, `total` (don't call it [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), that's a Python built-in), initialise it to `0` and add `number` to it with each iteration. You'd do this in much the same way as you're currently calculating `numbersEntered`.

Then you need to correct your `average` calculation to take `total` into account.

Comment: N.B: I didn't include any code here, as this looks like a learning exercise.

Comment: Thank you for not just giving me the code, I want to learn :). I am trying to think of ways to add the numbers together with each iteration but I cannot wrap my head around a way to do it.

Comment: I have figured it out! After initializing "total" all I had to do was write "total += number" within the while loop. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well done. Similarly, you can change `numbersEntered=numbersEntered+1` to be `numbersEntered += 1`.